# Adding a slide animation to changing a UIImageView's image

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I am attempting to make a sliding animation that will slowly slide in a new image, while replacing the previous image. So as the new image grows in width, the previous image will shrink in width. Similar to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20loading%20animation&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHgenvua7oAhVJKawKHc6QAbgQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1440&bih=740#imgrc=0ro5TQWt1BY7TM), except only from left-right and non-curved.

```
func setupLoad() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(animateImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func animateImage() {
    let icons = [WeatherIcons.clear, WeatherIcons.snow, WeatherIcons.fog, WeatherIcons.moon, WeatherIcons.wind, WeatherIcons.sleet, WeatherIcons.rain, WeatherIcons.overcast]

    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0...icons.count-1)
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = .moveIn
    transition.duration = 2
    transition.subtype = .fromLeft
    logoImage.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    logoImage.image = icons[randomIndex]
}
```

My current code slides in the image, while moving the frame and without the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *wipe*. Start with two image views, one on top of the other. Give the front image view a black mask. Animate the mask off to the right; that will animate emptiness (of the mask) in from the left, revealing the back image view.

[image]